# What's the tense for repetitive past action?

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, past-habitual

In English, "would" usually denotes a conditional voice.  "If I were sleepy, I would go to bed."

But I've caught myself using it to denote repetitive or habitual past action.  "On Thursdays, we would go to the dump to shoot rats."  It sounds perfectly idiomatic (and I don't know what I could replace it with.)

What is this called?  Is the imperfect in Spanish roughly the same thing?

Comment: You *could* replace it with '... we went to the dump to shoot rats, as well as 'used to'.  But your construction is perfectly normal.

Comment: Re Spanish, you should consider asking on linguistics.SE.

Comment: In this usage *would* means the same thing as *used to* [(v2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used%20). I think the latter is probably slightly more common in spoken English, if you were looking for something to replace it with.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to replace it with anything as it is officially a perfectly grammatical usage of [would](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would):

> Would (3): Used to; was or were habitually accustomed to ( + bare infinitive); indicating an action in the past that happened repeatedly or commonly. [from 9th c.]

The example from the Wiktionary:

> When we were kids we would sit by the radio with a tape recorder on a Sunday, listening out for the chart songs we wanted to have.
>   ~ *2009, "Soundtrack of my life", The Guardian, 15 Mar 09*

Although as you can see, the dictionary states *used to* as an alternative, therefore if you feel the need to, you may rewrite your original sentence to:

> On Thursdays, we used to go to the dump to shoot rats.

And still retain the original meaning.

Answer (score 5):

English only has two real morphological tenses left, Present and Past. And they're not really all that well distinguished; English morphology is almost all gone now.

All verbs, except modal auxiliary verbs, have a Present tense form (*is, am, are, has, have, goes, go, set,* etc.) and a (usually different) Past tense form (*was, were, had, went, came, set,* etc.). The present tense form is equivalent to the infinitive form, except that the 3sg form (subject *he/she/it*) is inflected with the {-Z₃} 3spres suffix. Those other things that people call "tenses" aren't, I'm afraid. Further discussion of English tenses and non-tenses can be found [here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/tense.html).

However, *would* **is** a modal auxiliary verb, and all English modals are defective, lacking infinitive forms (**I want to can do that*), past participles (**I have must do that*), and past tense forms for the most part. The old past tense forms have become modals in their own right, with their own syntax, idioms, exceptions, and curiosities, though they can still function as past markers, in some constructions.

More importantly, all English modals are ambiguous; each has at least two kinds of meaning:

- **Deontic**, involving human social phenomena like obligation, permission, ability, desire
- **Epistemic**, involving logical calculations about possibility and necessity

More details on modals can be found [here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html).

*Would* was formed from the past tense of a pre-defective *will*, and has many of the same base senses, somewhat modified. In particular, it can still function as the past tense of a **deontic** habitual use of *will*, which means, after all, "want, desire, be willing"; it's the **epistemic** use of *will* that means "future prediction", and this is normally repetitive in sense, because that's characteristic of things one does willingly:

- *The old man will spend hours just staring at the ocean.* (at some current time(s)
- *The old man would spend hours just staring at the ocean.* (at some previous time(s)

That's the deontic sense of *would*; it involves desire and **will**ingness.

The epistemic sense is the conditional one (the subjunctive mood verb form, when English had a subjunctive mood, was based on the past tense form of the verb, so this is a normal development). But this isn't a conditional.

Comment: I don’t see how you will ever convince a Frenchman that *je fus* is a past tense but *j’ai éte* is a present tense, any moreso than you will ever convince a Spaniard that only *amara* is a (literary) pluperfect and that *había amado* is somehow in the imperfect not in the pluperfect. That simply is not the way people talk about tense, John, whether it’s in French or Spanish, or in English. With these multiword verbal phrases using auxiliaries, it is the entire thing that people refer to as having a tense.  Yes, the *passé composé* is a compound tense, but it’s still a past: see *passé*.

Comment: French and Spanish are inflected languages. They actually have many different forms that fit into a tense system. English has simply lost all that -- there are only [9 inflectional morphemes left](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) in English. Talking about English "compound tenses" implies there is an English tense system, and there isn't.  It's that simple. And I'm not interested in convincing anybody about facts. Facts are self-demonstrating, and opinions are free.

Comment: You do learners a disservice when they come to you saying they have a future-tense verb like *amabo/amaré/aimerai* and ask how to translate that into the future tense for English, and you slap them down with academic nonsense claiming that they cannot do that because English has no future tense. Nonsense! It means you cannot converse with people. Yet if they had merely stricken the banned word *tense* from their question, you could have given them the simple answer to the simple question: the English future is *will love* or sometimes *shall love*. Stop making easy things hard for people!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't give them **that** answer, anyway. No native English speaker ever uses _shall_ for the future, or for anything else outside a couple fixed phrases and legal terminology. After teaching for 40+ years I've learned you do nobody a favor by lying to them. If you don't like it, I'm sorry; but I'm not in charge of what you read or how you interpret it. And vice versa.

Comment: Your assertion that no native speaker ever uses *shall* for the future is trivially disproven. And you’re evading the real issue completely.  You do indeed lie when you deceive them with sophistry.  You alone are in charge of that, and you are correct that I don’t like it.  Use a different word for your special inflectional sense of tense, ***because that is not how native speakers or foreign learners, or the OED, use that word.*** Or take it up with the OED, as they also disagree with you. See below for the normal nonspecialist definition of that word, which even specialists use.

Comment: OED: “Gram. Any one of the different forms or modifications (or word-groups) in the conjugation of a verb which indicate the different times (past, present, or future) at which the action or state denoted by it is viewed as happening or existing, and also (by extension) the different nature of such action or state, as continuing (imperfect) or completed (perfect); also abstr. that quality of a verb which depends on the expression of such differences.” Cite: 1876 Mason Eng. Gram. (ed. 21) §212 ― The tenses of the English verb are made partly by inflection, partly by the use of auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler Now that I have read the second sentence of your second comment, I shall stop telling people that I am a native speaker of English.  I shall find this somewhat sad, as there is no other language that I speak fluently.  Nor for that matter, is there any other language that either of my parents or any of my grandparents have been able to speak fluently.  We shall all be left unable to communicate, I suppose.

Comment: I'm with John. The problem with claiming that _I will go_ is the future tense is that there is no morphological test that distinguishes it from _I may go_, which nobody calls a tense. Just because a form corresponds to a future tense in languages which have one, does not mean that it is one. I am reminded of Alexander Gil's _Logonomia Anglica_ (1616 IIRC) which solemnly sets out the paradigm of the "future subjunctive": _That I may be hereafter_; _that thou mayst be hereafter_ etc.

Comment: (I'm not with John on "shall")

Comment: And I meant to say "no morphological or syntactic test".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *would* can be used for the imperfect tense in English (also known as the "past continuous" or "past progressive" tense.)

The following constructions could also be used:

> On Thursdays, we used to go to the dump to shoot rats.
>
> On Thursdays, we were going to the dump to shoot rats.

Comment: Most linguists (Huddleston and Pullum are exceptions) recognize only two English tenses, present and past. A tense is a change in the finite form of the verb that typically (but not invariably) indicates when an action takes place. The present tense of regular verbs, for example, has the same form as the plain form, except in the third person singular, while the past tense is marked by the suffix ‘-ed’ in all persons. ‘Would’, like 'used to', can certainly indicate habitual action, but it remains invariable, meaning it shows no inflections for person, number or tense.

Answer (score 1):

*Would* is a modal auxiliary verb expressing, primarily, unreal meaning (as in your first example), and, secondarily, habit (as in your second example), prediction and volition. As a modal verb, it is invariable and cannot helpfully be said to be in any tense.

Your sentence *If I were sleepy, I would go to bed* is an example of what is known as the Second Conditional. (The First Conditional would be *If I am sleepy, I go to bed* and the Third Conditional *If I had been sleepy, I would have gone to bed*.)

Comment: I disagree with your first statement. *Would* as an auxiliary can be used for the imperfect or past continuous tense.

Comment: @ghoppe: Every grammar book I possess says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of *would* you describe is simply the past tense of *will*. It is perfectly legitimate.